# Better Time Complexity for a Sequential Necessary Regex Script?

Tags: c++, regex, time-complexity, std

Using regex to parse and identify different types of data
Without including regex in my notation I have an informal O(n^3) time complexity
and a formal notation of
O(20.33n^3+84.22n^2+3n+14)
Decimals due to running n through 9 threads to segment it.

I require the first for loop to group regex matches(9 total regex to iterate) on a per line basis

The n^2 layer of for loops is used for sregex iterators

And the n^3 layer of for loops is used to verify that the match being stored is not a duplicate match

Initially I attempted to split this parsing function into 9 threads, and while it shaved off a lot of processing; My code now averages ~8 seconds for 750 matched cases
With a ~0.01s per case run speed.
Which is not at all the speeds I'd be expecting from regex cases

I've specified my regex as far as I can, and I pull substrings out of the match string per each case match so there's less data to pass to the next regex to shorten the duration more.

(I'm using std::regex)

Regex, while being the most costly part of my program, in it's current state needs to be as beefy as it is, as I'm comparing both filenames/paths and domains, and the best theory to differentiate these two I've thought of is a list of TLDs(ccTLDs also etc.)

I'm mainly wondering if there's any theoretical or actual way I can improve the general concept of my code, as being a O(n^3) function, even divided into 9ths is still fairly slow.

All I can think of would be either removing first n+1 for loop and substituting it by using a 2 dimensional vector to store index values to show line association, or implementing more conditional statements and non-regex functions to reduce the likelihood of worst-cases but I'm neither knowledgable or skilled enough to know if either is the best way to go about improving performance

The Full n+1 for loop is as follows(I've omitted the regex variables, and the wrapping function for readabilities sake):

```
for(unsigned int i = 0;i < lc; i++) {

                this->iocGroupHeader(this->finalpath);

                for(std::sregex_iterator i2 = std::sregex_iterator(lines[i].begin(), lines[i].end(), hashregfull);i2 != std::sregex_iterator();++i2 ) {
                    string debugline = lines[i];
                    unsigned long sv = termassoc.size();
                    smatch hashmatch = *i2;
                    unsigned long k = 0;
                    newline = "";
                    if( sv > k){
                        int added = 0;
                        for(unsigned int i4 = 0;i4 < termassoc.size(); i4++) {
                            if(termassoc[i4] == hashmatch.str() && added == 0) {
                               added++;
                           }
                            if(added != 0) break;
                        }
                        if(added == 0){
                            termassoc.emplace_back(hashmatch.str());
                            string hash = hashmatch.str();
                            if(hash.size() == 32) {
                                this->md5info(hash,this->finalpath );
                            } else if(hash.size() == 40) {
                                this->sha1info(hash,this->finalpath );
                            } else if(hash.size() == 64) {
                                this->sha256info(hash,this->finalpath );
                            }
                            added++;

                            unsigned long pos = lines[i].find(hashmatch.str());
                            newline += lines[i].substr(0, pos);
                            newline += lines[i].substr((hashmatch.str().size()) + pos, lines[i].size() - 1);
                        }else break;
                     } else {
                        termassoc.emplace_back(hashmatch.str());
                        string hash = hashmatch.str();
                        if(hash.size() == 32) {
                            this->md5info(hash,this->finalpath );
                        } else if(hash.size() == 40) {
                            this->sha1info(hash,this->finalpath );
                        } else if(hash.size() == 64) {
                            this->sha256info(hash,this->finalpath );
                        }
                        string str = hashmatch.str();
                        unsigned long pos = lines[i].find(str);
                        newline += lines[i].substr(0, pos);
                        newline += lines[i].substr((str.size()) + pos, lines[i].size() - 1);
                     }

                }
                if(newline != ""){
                    lines[i] = newline;
                } else { this->iocGroupFooter(this->finalpath); continue; }
                for(std::sregex_iterator i2 = std::sregex_iterator(lines[i].begin(), lines[i].end(), emailregfull);i2 != std::sregex_iterator();++i2 ) {
                    unsigned long sv = termassoc.size();
                    smatch emailmatch = *i2;
                    newline = "";
                    unsigned long k = 0;
                    if( sv > k){
                        int added = 0;
                        for(unsigned int i4 = 0;i4 < termassoc.size(); i4++) {
                            if(termassoc[i4] == emailmatch.str() && added == 0) {
                                added++;

                           }
                            if(added != 0) break;
                        }
                        if(added == 0){
                            termassoc.emplace_back(emailmatch.str());
                            this->emailinfo(emailmatch.str(),this->finalpath );
                            added++;
                            unsigned long pos = lines[i].find(emailmatch.str());
                            newline += lines[i].substr(0, pos);
                            newline += lines[i].substr((emailmatch.str().size()) + pos, lines[i].size() - 1);
                        }else break;
                     } else {
                        termassoc.emplace_back(emailmatch.str());
                        string output = emailmatch.str();
                        this->emailinfo(emailmatch.str(),this->finalpath );
                        unsigned long pos = lines[i].find(emailmatch.str());
                        newline += lines[i].substr(0, pos);
                        newline += lines[i].substr((emailmatch.str().size()) + pos, lines[i].size() - 1);

                     }
                }
                if(newline != ""){
                    lines[i] = newline;
                } else { this->iocGroupFooter(this->finalpath); continue; }
                if(file == false){
                    if(!(regex_search(lines[i], ipregfull) || this->containsRemoveHKEY(lines[i]) == "" || regex_search(lines[i], fileregblacklist2)) && (regex_search(lines[i], fileregpart2) || regex_search(lines[i], fileregpart1))) {
                        for(std::sregex_iterator i2 = std::sregex_iterator(lines[i].begin(), lines[i].end(), fileregpart1);i2 != std::sregex_iterator();++i2 ){
                            unsigned long sv = termassoc.size();
                            smatch filematch = *i2;
                            newline = "";
                            unsigned long k = 0;
                            if( sv > k){
                                int added = 0;
                                if(added == 0){
                                    termassoc.emplace_back(filematch.str());
                                    this->fileinfo(filematch.str(),this->finalpath );
                                    added++;
                                    unsigned long pos = lines[i].find(filematch.str());
                                    newline += lines[i].substr(0, pos);
                                    newline += lines[i].substr((filematch.str().size()) + pos, lines[i].size() - 1);
                                }else break;
                             } else {
                                termassoc.emplace_back(filematch.str());
                                string output = filematch.str();
                                this->fileinfo(filematch.str(),this->finalpath );
                                unsigned long pos = lines[i].find(filematch.str());
                                newline += lines[i].substr(0, pos);
                                newline += lines[i].substr((filematch.str().size()) + pos, lines[i].size() - 1);

                             }
                        }
                        if(newline != ""){
                            lines[i] = newline;
                        } else { this->iocGroupFooter(this->finalpath); continue; }
                        for(std::sregex_iterator i2 = std::sregex_iterator(lines[i].begin(), lines[i].end(), fileregpart2);i2 != std::sregex_iterator();++i2 ){
                            unsigned long sv = termassoc.size();
                            smatch filematch = *i2;
                            newline = "";
                            unsigned long k = 0;
                            if( sv > k){
                                int added = 0;
                                if(added == 0){
                                    termassoc.emplace_back(filematch.str());
                                    this->fileinfo(filematch.str(),this->finalpath );
                                    added++;
                                    unsigned long pos = lines[i].find(filematch.str());
                                    newline += lines[i].substr(0, pos);
                                    newline += lines[i].substr((filematch.str().size()) + pos, lines[i].size() - 1);
                                }else break;
                             } else {
                                termassoc.emplace_back(filematch.str());
                                string output = filematch.str();
                                this->fileinfo(filematch.str(),this->finalpath );
                                unsigned long pos = lines[i].find(filematch.str());
                                newline += lines[i].substr(0, pos);
                                newline += lines[i].substr((filematch.str().size()) + pos, lines[i].size() - 1);

                             }
                        }
                    }
                    if(newline != ""){
                        lines[i] = newline;
                    } else { this->iocGroupFooter(this->finalpath); continue; }
                }
                for(std::sregex_iterator i2 = std::sregex_iterator(lines[i].begin(), lines[i].end(), hkeyregfull);i2 != std::sregex_iterator();++i2 ){
                    unsigned long sv = termassoc.size();
                    smatch hkeymatch = *i2;
                    newline = "";
                    unsigned long k = 0;
                    if( sv > k){
                        int added = 0;
                        for(unsigned int i4 = 0;i4 < termassoc.size(); i4++) {
                            if(termassoc[i4] == hkeymatch.str() && added == 0) {
                                added++;

                           }
                            if(added != 0) break;
                        }
                        if(added == 0){
                            termassoc.emplace_back(hkeymatch.str());
                            this->reginfo(hkeymatch.str(),this->finalpath );
                            added++;
                            unsigned long pos = lines[i].find(hkeymatch.str());
                            newline += lines[i].substr(0, pos);
                            newline += lines[i].substr((hkeymatch.str().size()) + pos, lines[i].size() - 1);
                        }else break;
                     } else {
                        termassoc.emplace_back(hkeymatch.str());
                        string output = hkeymatch.str();
                        this->reginfo(hkeymatch.str(),this->finalpath );
                        unsigned long pos = lines[i].find(hkeymatch.str());
                        newline += lines[i].substr(0, pos);
                        newline += lines[i].substr((hkeymatch.str().size()) + pos, lines[i].size() - 1);

                     }
                }
                if(newline != ""){
                    lines[i] = newline;
                } else { this->iocGroupFooter(this->finalpath); continue; }
                for(std::sregex_iterator i2 = std::sregex_iterator(lines[i].begin(), lines[i].end(), ipregfull);i2 != std::sregex_iterator();++i2 ){
                    unsigned long sv = termassoc.size();
                    smatch ipmatch = *i2;
                    newline = "";
                    unsigned long k = 0;
                    if( sv > k){
                        int added = 0;
                        for(unsigned int i4 = 0;i4 < termassoc.size(); i4++) {
                            if(!(termassoc[i4] == ipmatch.str()) && added == 0) {
                                added++;

                           }
                            if(added != 0) break;
                        }
                        if(added == 0){
                            termassoc.emplace_back(ipmatch.str());
                            this->ipinfo(ipmatch.str(),this->finalpath );
                            added++;
                            unsigned long pos = lines[i].find(ipmatch.str());
                            newline += lines[i].substr(0, pos);
                            newline += lines[i].substr((ipmatch.str().size()) + pos, lines[i].size() - 1);
                        }else break;
                     } else {
                        termassoc.emplace_back(ipmatch.str());
                        string output = ipmatch.str();
                        this->ipinfo(ipmatch.str(),this->finalpath );
                        unsigned long pos = lines[i].find(ipmatch.str());
                        newline += lines[i].substr(0, pos);
                        newline += lines[i].substr((ipmatch.str().size()) + pos, lines[i].size() - 1);

                     }
                }
                if(newline != ""){
                    lines[i] = newline;
                } else { this->iocGroupFooter(this->finalpath); continue; }
                for(std::sregex_iterator i2 = std::sregex_iterator(lines[i].begin(), lines[i].end(), domainregfull);i2 != std::sregex_iterator();++i2 ){
                    unsigned long sv = termassoc.size();
                    smatch domainmatch = *i2;
                    unsigned long k = 0;
                    if( sv > k){
                        int added = 0;
                        for(unsigned int i4 = 0;i4 < termassoc.size(); i4++) {
                            if(!(termassoc[i4] == domainmatch.str()) && added == 0) {
                                termassoc.emplace_back(domainmatch.str());
                                this->domaininfo(domainmatch.str(),this->finalpath );
                                added++;
                           }
                            if(added != 0) break;
                       }
                     } else {
                        termassoc.emplace_back(domainmatch.str());
                        string output = domainmatch.str();
                        this->domaininfo(domainmatch.str(),this->finalpath );
                     }
                }
                this->iocGroupFooter(this->finalpath);
            }
```

The Minimal Concept Would Look Like:

```
for(i = 0; i < linecount; i++){

for(i2 = regex iterator;i2 != regex iterator;i2++){
    for(i3 = 0; i3 < termstorage; i3++){

    }
}
for(i2 = regex iterator;i2 != regex iterator;i2++){
    for(i3 = 0; i3 < termstorage; i3++){

    }
}
for(i2 = regex iterator;i2 != regex iterator;i2++){
    for(i3 = 0; i3 < termstorage; i3++){

    }
}
for(i2 = regex iterator;i2 != regex iterator;i2++){
    for(i3 = 0; i3 < termstorage; i3++){

    }
}
for(i2 = regex iterator;i2 != regex iterator;i2++){
    for(i3 = 0; i3 < termstorage; i3++){

    }
}
for(i2 = regex iterator;i2 != regex iterator;i2++){
    for(i3 = 0; i3 < termstorage; i3++){

    }
}
for(i2 = regex iterator;i2 != regex iterator;i2++){
    for(i3 = 0; i3 < termstorage; i3++){

    }
}
```

**Edit** Other possibilities I've thought of expanding on the concept of indexing matches, I think its possible to decrease the time complexity to an O(n) by also replacing the O(n^3) loop with a post-processing filter function, and generating results afterwards?
**edit2**The Function calls within the n^3+1 loop are all O(1) functions so you can consider them as such

Comment: Added full problem O(n^3) loop, and a minimal O(n^3) version

Comment: I do not understand what your code does. It would be a lot simpler to try to answer the question if I knew what you were doing and why you are convinced that nested regular expressions are the way to get there. The code you paste is, with high probability, much more complex than it needs to be to showcase the problem. Can you come up with a [SCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) and explain the task you are trying to solve? Unrelated note: how did you calculate the "formal notation" complexity? (I am unaware of any accurate & practical way to do that given modern CPU architectures)...